# ModSecurity and CIDR notation to block multiple IPs at the same time

Tags: fail2ban

I use ModSecurity and Fail2Ban on Apache2.4

Often times I get a mischievous hit on the server that tries to do something bad.  No problem, Modsecurity and Fail2Ban catches it and bans THAT IP.

For example, 192.99.13.29 will attempt to use an Injection attack and it is blocked, but then 192.99.13.30, then 192.99.13.31 and so on so that in effect, they get as many shots at cracking in as they please.

What I want to know is can I alter Fail2Ban so that instead of just banning that ONE IP, I can use CIDR notation to ban the entire range for that particular IP address on the first hit?

For example, instead of 192.99.13.29 being blacklisted in IPTABLES, I want 192.99.13.29/24 blacklisted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By the way, this is on an Apache 2.4 server on Linux.
The answer was to go to one of the online sources that provide CIDR notation by Country.
So I simply got the CIDR IP list for the entire USA and in my Virtual host for the domain in question, I added a Deny,Allow statement then Allowed all the USA IP's and added a Deny from All at the end of that list.

That is working, but it's not ideal.   I think putting the list in the 000-default Apache2 configuration would be better because it would them apply to ALL connections to the server....but it didn't work that way for me.

Comment: This solution is assuming that the bad guys will never use addresses that - at the time of your setup - were on that list.